# gesture recognizer doesn't work on subview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

At first,I attach UISwipeGestureRecognizer to a image view,the action method can't be triggered.Then I attach UISwipeGestureRecognizer to view controller's view,it works well.I don't know why.
here is the code that doesn't work

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction)];
    swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    //imageView is an outlet of image view
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}
```

here is the code that works well

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction)];
    swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    //imageView is an outlet of image view
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add this code to imageView:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one
`[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`